# Multiple same windows with different instances in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2013

I am new to WPF and have been writing a program that shows a list of results in a ListView box for a while. Each element in the box is clickable and a detail window will show up if you click on an element in the list. I want this program to be able to show several detail windows of different elements at the same time.

Right now I only have this:

```
DetailWindow w = new DetailWindow();
w.show();
```

These two lines are in the element click event listener. Every time the I click on the element, a new window pops up, but it always points to the same instance as the old ones(all the detail windows on the screen shares the same instance). All the variables and fields have the same values.

Is there a way to force it to create a different window instance every time I click on the elements? Thanks so much!

In the Detail Window's contructor: (USER_ID is a field in Detail Window)

```
USER_ID = MainWindow.getUserID(); // Assume getUserID() always returns correct ID
```

There is a button in the Detail window which starts the SQL querys
In the Detail Window's Button listener:

```
// Get info from database by using the USER_ID field
string SQL_CMD = "..."; 
... // Bunch of SQL stuff
dt.Load(reader); // dt is a DataTable which stores the results from reader

foreach(element in dt)
    RESULT_LIST.Add(...) // Adds data into RESULT_LIST from dt. RESULT_LIST is a field.

DetailViewList.ItemSource = RESULT_LIST; // DetailViewList is the name of the ListView
```

This works correctly at the beginning. First window has the correct list of user1 after button click. The second window pops up has the correct user -- user2, but the list in the second window will have all the elements of user1 and user2 after button click. If I click the button in the first window, the list will shows the same results as in the second window.

Comment: do you mean it's a different instance of the window but the same view model instance thus showing the same values in all windows?

Comment: Yes. I want the DetailWindow.XAML to show up after every click but every DetailWindow.XAML has its own instance.

Comment: where is the model being loaded?

Comment: you are creating new instances....but it's showing you the same data because I suspect the datacontext is the same instance. Can you show how you bind the datacontext for your view?

Comment: I store the data inside of the DetailWindow.XAML.cs as fields actually... I didn't create a model class... Every time a new DetailWinodw starts, it reads data from a SQL database and stores the data in its fields.

Comment: how are you passing the selected item to the DetailWindow?

Comment: @KField `I store the data inside of the DetailWindow` - delete all that. Create a proper DataModel and use proper Data Binding and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: If you are reading from SQL and storing in DetailWindow.XAML.cs as fields you should have unique instances.  Post a simple sample to reproduce you problem.  How can DetailWindow know which detail?   Your problem statement does not add up.

Comment: @LeeO. I call a method in the MainWindow from the Detail window which returns an ID of the element I clicked.

Comment: @KField that does not answer the question of how the ID is passed to the DetailWindow. We need the smallest subset of code we could use to reproduce the issue in order to diagnose the problem. There could be many different causes.

Comment: @Blam The fields are actually not unique. I have a field called "FIRST_LAUNCH" which I added to check the uniqueness. It is true by default. A message box will shows its value right after the InitializeComponent() method in the constructor. I have a button in the DetailWindow which set this boolean to false. It shows true when the first window shows up, and I click the button. This boolean is always false in the later windows.

Comment: -1 Post some code to reproduce.  If you are really storing in storing in DetailWindow.XAML.cs then you would have unique instances.

Comment: I add more code in the post

Comment: You STILL have not posted where the variables are declared!  I wish I could -1 again.  Post code to reproduce.

Comment: Problem solved!! I was out of my mind and set all the fields to static. That's why they are all shared. After I deleted all the static term, they works perfectly now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!! I was out of my mind and set all the fields to static. That's why they are all shared. After I deleted all the static term, they works perfectly now.